# Execute Python From C# Without IronPython

Tags: c#, python, numpy, scipy

I have a application that is written in C# and we really want to use some of the scikit-learn, numpy and scipy stuff for machine learning. Ultimately, what I'd like to do is pass a few parameters to the Python script from the C# application, have Python process it and return me a value to use in C#.

Unfortunately, the [sci-kit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) stuff isn't compatible with IronPython so I cannot use that. I don't know what else I can do. I've thought of making a Python web service and then just calling that from the C# app, but I want to know if there are any other options.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible to execute shell code from C#? That's one way you could do it.

Comment: it's definitely possible, but i don't know of any off-the-shelf implementations. however, if you can go the other way, embedding C# into python is nearly trivial. but a couple more options: xml-rpc, boost.python...

Comment: sweeneyrod I am not sure since I have to pass parameter in and get output. I have been researching all day and can't find a good answer to that.

@CorleyBrigman I hadn't really thought of that way. I may look into doing that.

Comment: see the python.NET library for how to import C# into python. once you do, it is almost native python - you can tab-complete in the console, transfer many data types back and forth without any special handling, etc.